# Vertex.value() Property Not found Gremlin Neptune Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am accessing a neptune DataBase instance from a Lambda, I have successfully configured the connection of the neptune database from the lambda using the following

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
builder.addContactPoint("endpoint");
builder.port(8182);
builder.enableSsl(true);
builder.keyCertChainFile("SFSRootCAG2.pem");
```

I have even sent update and insert statements to the database using

```
GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
g.addV("Custom Label").property(T.id, "CustomId1").property("name", "Custom id vertex 1").next();
```

But when I try to retrieve properties of the vertex

```
Vertex vertex = g.V().has(T.id, "CustomId1").next(); System.out.println((String) vertex.value("name"));
```

I receive the error that the property name doesn't not exist on that vertex:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The property does not exist as the key has no associated value for the provided element: v[CustomId1]:name
```

Can someone please let me know that is the mistake i am making here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertex you get back from the query is known as a reference vertex. It will only contain an ID and a label. For properties you need you should explicitly ask for them using a step like `values`, `project` or `valueMap`.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, what is the best way to configure the gremlin server to create UUID by default for vertices?

Comment: It would be best to ask that as a new question as this one was on a different topic. The Gremlin Server has configurable ID managers.